# What is the definition of equicontinuity in topological spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, reference-request

Let $X, Y$ be two topological spaces and let $\mathcal F$ be a family of functions from $X$ into $Y$. What is the definition of equicontinuity for $\mathcal F$?

If $Y$ was a metric space then $\mathcal F$ is equicontinuous at $x$ if for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|< \epsilon$ for all $y\in U$ and all $f\in \mathcal F$.

However I can not extend this definition to a topological space.

Comment: Any thoughts about the answer?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks for the answer. I read about action $\sigma:S\times X\to X$ of  a semigroup $S$ on a compact Hausdorff topological space X. Definition of equicontinuous action is: the family $\sigma_s$ in $X^X$ be equicontinuous. After your answer I searched and found that every compact hausdorff topological space has a unifom structure compatible with its topology. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not surprising, since this concept does not exist for topological spaces. However, there is a concept of a [uniform space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space) which is somewhere between a metric space and a topological space. (Every metric space is a uniform space and every uniform space is a topological space.) Equicontinuity still makes sense for uniform spaces, see  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space#Uniform_continuity).